# Pell's equation for polynomials?

Tags: polynomials, pell-type-equations

Is there any way to solve the equation $$p^2-(x^2-1)q^2=1$$ for $p,q\in\mathbb{Z}[x]$?

I know how to solve Pell's equations on $\mathbb{Z}$, but I have no idea how to solve its polynomial analogue. Is there any theory that can do this?

Answer (score 2):

Setting
$$\left(x+\sqrt{x^2-1}\right)^n=p_n+q_n\sqrt{x^2-1}$$
gives infinitely many solutions $(p_n,q_n)$. I suspect these
are essentially all of them.

Comment: Is there any way to get all solutions?

Comment: @Colescu: The smallest positive integer solution is $p=x,\,q=1$, as $q$ can't get any smaller. Using this fundamental solution, it is well-known that all others can be generated using powers of $(p+q\sqrt{d})^n$.

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII Is it well-known? I know that this holds if $p,q$ are integers, but what about the polynomial case?

Comment: @WillJagy: Colescu, the linear polynomial case $p,q$ should generalize to higher cases. Jagy will be more familiar with this.